# how to get pin_ptr to static field or variable in C++ cli

Tags: c++-cli

I have static variable of type long in the managed class. I have to pass its address to the native function (interlockedIncrement). Address of Non-static variable can be assigned to pin_ptr, but we can not compile it for the static. Are there any work arounds?

```
    private:
     static long s_x  = 0;
     long m_x;
    ...
...
    // inside method
      pin_ptr<long> pstatic = &s_x; // does not compiles
      pin_ptr<long> pMember = &m_x; // compiles
```

Is your class a ref class?

> > yes
> >     If yes there is no issue with the code.
> >     but it is not compiled
> >     If no then you can't initialize the static value this way. Please add more code. Thanks

The code sample enough to show the issue:

```
// .h
ref class ManagedClass
{     
    private:
  // Number of instances of this class
  static __int64 mSTField = 0;
    __int64 mField;
}

// .cpp
ManagedClass:: ManagedClass()
{
   pin_ptr<__int64 > mSTPtr = &mSTField; // does not compile. “cannot convert interior_ptr to pin_ptr”
   pin_ptr<__int64 > mPtr   = & mField; // compiles
   InterlockedIncrement((__int64*) mSTPtr); // Native method does work only in case if mSTPtr is “pin_ptr”
}
```

Comment: Showing the actual compiler error is often quite useful.

Comment: Is your class a `ref class`? If yes there is no issue with the code. If no then you can't initialize the static value this way. Please add more code. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

```
pin_ptr<__int64> mSTPtr = pin_ptr<__int64>(&mSTField);
```

[image: pointer conversion]